# Windows service not executing code

Tags: c#, windows, multithreading, service

I am a little new to windows services and threading so I hope I am not making an obvious mistake here.  I have an application I developed for running various network maintenance type activities in C#.  The application works perfectly on my local machine, I decided I wanted it to run as a windows service so using the same code made the appropriate changes and again works great on my local machine.

My problem arises when I port it over a server on my network.  The non-windows service code again works great and runs as expected.  However the windows service code just seems to do nothing.  The process installs fine and starts/stops fine but none of the code seems to be executing, any help on debugging windows services in visual studio would also be appreciated.  Here is the code in my OnStart procedure that does not seem to be executing.

```
        smThread = new Thread(delegate() { sm.RunServerMonitor(ref run); });
        smThread.Start();

        dailyThread = new Thread(delegate() { dailyEvents(); });
        dailyThread.Start();
```

Because the non-windows service code works I don't believe I am running into at permissions type issue, unless there are different permissions that need to be set to allow services to perform tasks remotely than I would need for plain c# code doing the same.

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: Can you show us the code you are using to connect to the service? And when you say windows service do you mean a WCF service?

Comment: it could be permission issue. what's the account running the service? your desktop app could run as administrator, the service could run as a different one which does not have the permission.

Comment: If you are running this was a WCF web service, you'll probably need to change the app pool account settings.  The default IIS_IUSR accounts don't have many permissions.  Are you running WCF?

Comment: What is it the you mean by "to perform tasks remotely"? Services _generally_ do not have permission to access network resources. You would have to change the login account for the service.

Comment: It is not a WCF service, how do I set the service to run as administrator?

Comment: The code I used to create this service...

        public WindowsService()
        {
            this.ServiceName = "Network Admin";
            //this.EventLog = "Application";
            this.CanHandlePowerEvent = true;
            this.CanHandleSessionChangeEvent = true;
            this.CanPauseAndContinue = true;
            this.CanShutdown = true;
            this.CanStop = true;

        }

Comment: By run tasks remotely I mean there are several machines on the network and I perform various tasks on each such as gathering perfmon data, gathering hard disk data, syncing the system clocks etc.  How would I go about setting the appropriate permissions to allow my service to do this?

Comment: goto administrative tools->Services, select your service, right click, property, choose logon, where you can find what account it is using. it has to have the permission to do these jobs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for the comments, the problem was permission related.  When I clicked on the service and under the "log on" tab and changed the account to one with administrative privileges and it works fine.  Thanks everyone for you help it's greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Add the following line as the first line of code inside your `OnStart` method

```
while(!System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
}

smThread = new Thread(delegate() { sm.RunServerMonitor(ref run); });
smThread.Start();

dailyThread = new Thread(delegate() { dailyEvents(); });
dailyThread.Start();
```

You can set up a breakpoint in your code on the next line after the `while` loop and start the service. Then, from Visual Studio, attach to the process of the service for debugging.